# How to iterate through single <key, value> pairs of List in dart

Tags: list, dictionary, dart

I have 2 Lists (`uid` and `url`) that are growable, and I need to set the first `List` as the key and the second as value. At some point, i'll have a 3rd List (`randomUids`) which will be keys and will print out the corresponding values. Here is the example code:

```
   List<String> uid = ["uid1", "uid2","uid3","uid4"]; //Lists will grow larger after a while
   List<String> url = ["url1","url2","url3","url4"]; 
   List<String> randomUids = ["uid4", "uid2"];
```

When I try:

```
   Map<List, List> mapKeyValue = Map();
              mapKeyValue[uid] = url;
     print( uid.contains(randomUids));
```

I get a *false*. Also, the print returns **uid** and **url** Lists as 2 long indices instead of separate Strings. How can I iterate the List so that **url**.contains(**randomUids**) is *true*. Also how can I print out the values of randomUids.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try:
>
> ```dart
> print( uid.contains(randomUids));
> ```
>
> I get a *false*.

Your code asks if `uid` (a `List` of `String`s) contains `randomUids` (another `List` of `String`s).  It returns false because `uid`'s elements are not `List`s; they're `String`s.

Presuming that you want the *n*th element of `uid` to correspond to the *n*th element of `url`, and you can guarantee that `uid.length == url.length`, you can construct a `Map` of UIDs to URLs:

```dart
assert(uid.length == url.length);
var uidMap = <String, String>{
  for (var i = 0; i < uid.length; i += 1)
    uid[i]: url[i],
};
```

And then you can iterate over `randomUids` and do lookups:

```dart
for (var uid in randomUids) {
  if (uidMap.containsKey(uid)) {
    print(uidMap[uid]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You absolutely nailed it. All I had to add was toString() inside the if statement: ie if(uidMap.toString().contains(uid)).......     Thank you very much.

Comment: @MR.B You shouldn't need to do that, and doing `uidMap.toString().contains(uid)` does something different.  It would incorrectly report true if you had `{'1234': 'url1'}` and asked if it contained the UID `'12'`.

Comment: Oh ok. I get what you mean. I ended up leaving it as 'containsKey()' ? I think that will pull out the entire Key instead of just a part of it. Somehow it doesnt accept just 'contains' on my side.

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake.  I meant to use `containsKey`.  Corrected.